# I don't understand what is happening with this XOR

Tags: javascript, xor

I am working on this problem. 
"Given an array, find the int that appears an odd number of times.
There will always be only one integer that appears an odd number of times."
I came up with this solution online:

```
function findOdd(A) {
var n = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
  n = n^A[i];
  }

  return n;
}
```

This works but I am not sure why and i was hoping someone could explain it to me. I just don't understand the line:

```
n = n^A[i];
```

Could you please tell me what it is doing in this instance?

Comment: Are you asking what XOR does?  Otherwise, what exactly is the contents of 'A' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xoring any number with itself will result in 0. If you know that there's only one number that appears an odd number of times, the others will cancel themselves out by self-xoring, and the answer will be the remaining number that appears an odd number of times.

Comment: And xoring 0 with any int is that int. And xor is associative and commutative. QED.

Answer (score 2):

XOR of two same numbers is always zero. That is,

`A^A=0`

So, if you XOR a particular number with itself repeatedly for even number of times, the result will be zero.

Here, initially the value of n is zero. The number that will be XOR-ed even number of times, will result zero. And the number that is present odd number of times, say `2m+1`number of times, will result in zero for 2m occurrences, and that same number for the final one occurrence.

This is how this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

^ is an exor bit wise operator . so when you do

- 1 ^ 1 is 0
- 0 ^ 1 is 1
- 1 ^ 0 is 1
- 0 ^  0 is 0

so to find the odd number of 1's the following code does is 
initially result is arr[0] is 1 .
so in the arrary 0^ 0 becomes 0 and 2 ^ 2 becomes 0 and there are 3 1's so 1^1 gets 0 and with 0 ^1 we are leftout with the number which repeats odd nubmer of times

```js
var arr=[1,1,1,0,0,2,2];
var result=arr[0];
for(var i=1;i<arr.length;i++)
  result=result ^ arr[i];

console.log(result);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise operators work on 32 bits numbers. Any numeric operand in the operation is converted into a 32 bit number. The result is converted back to a JavaScript number. `^` is a bitwise XOR javascript operator.

Bitwise XOR Operator returns a one in each bit position for which the corresponding bits of either but not both operands are ones.

a XOR b yields 1 if a and b are different. The truth table for the XOR operation is:

```
a   b       a XOR b

0   0         0
0   1         1
1   0         1
1   1         0
```

Explanation for expression `n = n^A[i];`

let `A = [1,2,3,4,5]`

for `n=0, i=0` => `0 ^ A[0]` => `0 ^ 1` => converted to binary `0000 ^ 0001` results to `0001` which is equal to `1`

for `n=1, i=1` => `1 ^ A[1]` => `1 ^ 1` => converted to binary `1111 ^ 0010` results to `1101` which is equal to `13`

and so on... Hope this solution helps you to understand the above expression and clear your all doubts.

Comment: 1 ^ 1 is equal to 0 not to 13